# What Method Should I Use to Keep the Order of Items with Keys in a List (Java)?

Tags: java, list

What method should I use to keep items in a list if :

1. I have a an object which contains a list of items and can do action on those items
2. Those items are ordered inside a list
3. I need to be able to change the position of items inside the list and add or remove an item based on its id.
4. The list will be saved into a database eventually (and items will need to keep their order inside this list)
5. It doesn't make sense to have a property "order" on the orderd items (these objects can be in multiple kind of lists).

The choices that I have (is there any other choices?) :

1. Use a List object so it will automatically keep the order. But I'll have to loop through all objects (at worse) to find an object by Id.
2. Use a map with a Key / Value (object id / object), so it'll be easy to retrieve the object (and fast) and keep another map that just keeps the order of the object (object Id / object order)

**Solution #1)** This seems like the easiest solution with a performance drawback.

**Solution #2)** This seems like the fastest solution but with a lot more code when reordering list.

Is there an object that I don't know about that would be ordered, have Key / Value pairs and have methods like object.add(index, key, value) or object.getByIndex(index) or object.getByKey(key)?

Comment: You can use linked hashmap, it takes in the advantage of lists(solution-1) and has objects can be retrieved using Keys like the way in solution-2-http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html

Comment: @Patton I don't think that I can change the position of an item with a LinkedHashMap?  I'll have to create a new LinkedHashMap and reinsert everything, no?

Comment: Yes you are right! I was wrong...! My apologies....

Comment: you will have to build you own data structure object, which combines hash map and array list. the O(1) access of hashmap and order of array list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `Roni` suggested you need to use your own data structure. I believe that is the only option viable to fill in your requirement.

I have done a sample to fill in your requirement as a `starting point` and you can build on it.

```
public class MapAndList {

    private List<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>();
    private Map<String, Object> keyValuePair = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    public void addItem(String key, Object item) {
        // TODO if the key is already present in the list throw exception
        keys.add(key);
        keyValuePair.put(key, item);
    }

    public void removeItem(String key) {
        keys.remove(key);
        keyValuePair.remove(key);
    }

    public void removteItem(int index) {
        removeItem(keys.get(index));
    }

    public void addItem(String key, Object item, int index) {
        keys.add(index, key);
        keyValuePair.put(key, item);
    }

}
```

Hope this helps you....

Comment: Thanks, I'll use that structure :)

Answer (score 0):

If your items are not going to get duplicated, then use indexOf() method to get index of object and then you can directly access object using get(int Index)

Also override equals method of Item object to return comparison based on ID hence your will get Id based retrial.

Just checked source code of indexOf method and it iterates through whole list only :(